# UseExceptionHandler ASP.NET Core Web API

Tags: c#, error-handling, swagger, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm trying to use `app.UseExceptionHandler("/error")` so I can handle all the errors using the `ProblemDetails`.

However, I never get rerouted to the `ErrorController`. When I set a breakpoint, the debugger never gets inside this endpoint.

Does anyone know why I'm not hitting my breakpoint?

The code in the `program.cs` is :

```
WebApplicationBuilder builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
{
    // Add services to the container.
    builder.Services.AddControllers();
    // Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
    builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
    builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
    builder.Services
            .AddApplication()
            .AddAInfrastructure(builder.Configuration);
}

WebApplication app = builder.Build();
{
    if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseSwagger();
        app.UseSwaggerUI(q => q.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json","PowerPlanner v1"));
    }

    app.UseExceptionHandler("/error"); // <===============
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseRouting();
    app.UseAuthorization();
    app.MapControllers();
}

app.Run();
```

Controller:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

[ApiController]
public class ErrorsController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet("/error")]
    public IActionResult Error()
    {
        return Problem();
    }
}
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. File new project with an exception in the WeatherForecast controller results hitting the ErrorController.

Comment: Looks like i figured it out, It's because the GET endpoints, get rerouted to the GET endpoints in the ErrorsController. I was trying a POST endpoint to get in the error GET endpoint. Is there any way I can reroute everything to 1? When i try to change the attribute to [Route("/error")] i get a `SwaggerGeneratorException: Ambiguous HTTP method for action`

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

Because I Used Swagger, I couldn't declare the route with the attribute `[Route("/error"])` without getting an error. To solve this, the entire controller has to be marked with :

`[ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi = true)]`

like this:

```
[ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi = true)] //<==== 
public class ErrorController : ControllerBase
{
    [Route("/error")] //<=== this can only be 'route' when the controller is marked with ignoreApi=false
    public IActionResult ErrorPost()
    {
        return Problem(;
    }
}
```

Documentation : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/handle-errors?view=aspnetcore-7.0